# How to use Angular7 (angular material) drag drop between two components

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular7, angular-cdk

As recently angular introduced drag and drop in angular material 
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview .

All examples describes with in a single component. How to use this in two different components, Drag one component item and drop into another component.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You may use properties **id** and **cdkDropListConnectedTo** to link both lists:

**Component 1:**

```
<div cdkDropList id="list-1" cdkDropListConnectedTo="list-2" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

**Component 2:**

```
<div cdkDropList id="list-2" cdkDropListConnectedTo="list-1" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

If you need to connect several lists to one list, you may use the following syntax: `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['list-1', 'list-2', 'list-3', 'list-4']"`

After linking the lists, you must correctly update one or both lists depending on the actions. You may do it on the drop function like this:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.container.id === event.previousContainer.id) {
      // move inside same list
      moveItemInArray(this.list, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      // move between lists
    }
}
```

For moving items between lists, you will possibly want to keep track of the lists centrally. You may do so by using a Service, a Store or other methods.

Comment: Thank you. This is coming fine for single drag block, if I want multiple like [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[list-2,list-3,list-4] is not working. how to achive that

Comment: @JomyJoseph I've updated the answer to include support for linking between multiple lists. If this solves your issue, please accept the answer. If not, let us know.

Comment: Sure. You are rock. I missed single quote for each id.

Comment: in angular 7.2.1 i had to use [] around cdkDropListConnectedTo to work even with one list.

`[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[list-1]"` or `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['list-1']"`

Comment: @Dirk tested it with angular 7.2.0 and angular material/cdk 7.2.1 and it worked using the same syntax as before: `cdkDropListConnectedTo="list-1"`

Comment: @GCSDC sorry, you're right. Tested right now and it works. don't know what was the mistake yesterday.

Comment: You saved my life sir. The Angular examples do not include the `id=""`-part, which was missing for me.

Comment: Hi man, and how would it be done to drag the columns, in the case of "MOVIES WATCHED", "MOVIE"?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437853/angular-cdk-drag-with-two-lists?noredirect=1#comment127968880_72437853

Answer (score 13):

Not sure if the above solution still works with angular 7.2.9 and angular material/cdk 7.3.5

It did not work for me and thus after some hard time - I managed to make it work using **cdkDropListGroup** directive. All **cdkDropList** within **cdkDropListGroup** will be available to drop items. You no longer need to connect Drop Lists with **cdkDropListConnectedTo** property

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
<component1></component1>
<component2></component2>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your implementation, can you provide sample cause I am facing this problem now and without connectedTo it does'nt work. I have component with list where drag-drop is implemented and I want to use it in such group.

Comment: Saved the day!!

Answer (score 11):

You just need to create a drop method in the service and call that drop method from two components. And have to wrap these two components with cdkDropListGroup on the parent component.

**App Component**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div cdkDropListGroup>
    <app-test1></app-test1>
    <app-test2></app-test2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Test1 Component**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Movies</h2>
  <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="MoviesList"
    class="movie-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
    <div class="movie-block" *ngFor="let moviesList of MoviesList" cdkDrag>{{moviesList}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

  export class Test1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private ss: ShareService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  // Transfer Items Between Lists
  MoviesList = [
    'The Far Side of the World',
    'Morituri',
    'Napoleon Dynamite',
    'Pulp Fiction',
    'Blade Runner',
    'Cool Hand Luke',
    'Heat',
    'Juice'    
  ];


  onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    this.ss.drop(event);
  }

}
```

**Test2 Component**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Movies Watched</h2>
  <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="MoviesWatched"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="list-1" class="movie-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
    <div class="movie-block" *ngFor="let moviesWatched of MoviesWatched" cdkDrag>{{moviesWatched}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { ShareService } from '../share.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test2',
  templateUrl: './test2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test2.component.css']
})
export class Test2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private ss: ShareService) { }

  MoviesWatched = [
   'Transformers'
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    this.ss.drop(event);
  }

}
```

**ShareService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';


@Injectable()
export class ShareService {

  constructor() { }

  public drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the working [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drag-drop-two-components)

Comment: Hi man, and how would it be done to drag the columns, in the case of "MOVIES WATCHED", "MOVIE"?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437853/angular-cdk-drag-with-two-lists?noredirect=1#comment127968880_72437853

Answer (score 2):

**Component1**

```
<div cdkDropList id="list-1" cdkDropListConnectedTo="list-2" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div *ngFor="let item of list" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

**Component 2**

```
<div cdkDropList id="list-2" cdkDropListConnectedTo="list-1" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let item of list" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</div>
</div>
```

**shared Service for both component**

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
            moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
            transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                event.container.data,
                event.previousIndex,
                event.currentIndex);
        }
    }
```

**Parent Component**

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
<component1></component1>
<component2></component2>
</div>
```

call drop method from both the component

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
      this.sharedService.drop(event);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect with the multiple list then use the blow code in drag and drop

```
[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['element-1', 'element-2', 'element-3', 'element-4']"
```