# Material drag and drop registry fails

Tags: angular, angular-material

When dragging from one list to the other often the event does not activate. Also often it does not recognise the other container as a droppable zone.

I tried putting the drag and drop on different elements, changing the css styling to hopefully get better detection. changing the general html structure.

I couldn't get it to work on stackblitz but here is it anyway to look into the code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glkn4v

general html for drag and drop lists

```
<div class="grouper" cdkDropList cdkDropListGroup id="list-one" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['list-two']" [cdkDropListData]="dataMap"
               (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" >
            <div *ngFor="let node of getMapKeys(); let i = index">
              <div class="main" cdkDropList>
                <div class="headnode">> {{node}}</div>
                <div class="subnode" *ngFor="let item of getmapkeyValues(node)" cdkDrag> <!--style="display: none;"-->
                  {{item}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I want the item to register it properly when its being dragged over a dropzone. It should also be droppable on each part of the tree like structure.

I'm very much a beginner in all this so sorry if all my code is bad.

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422624/6481438).

Comment: Thank you! This answer solved my issues.