# Two list with draggable elements angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-material-7

What I want is to have a schedule with draggable elements in between the time available, what I don't know is how to output two lists, the one with the draggable elements and the one with schedule and the times available, which can be dragged on
[image: this is what I want]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53422624/6481438) may help

Comment: I've tried that, the thing is that the list for the schedule is different to the one for the draggable elements

Comment: You may follow the same approach from the answer I pointed and consider each time as a separate `cdkDropList`.

Comment: My solution in the end was to change the UI, so that I don't have that problem, thank very much anyway