# Connect Element references between two components

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-component-router

I am trying to split a big components into smaller ones. I've implemented there drag&drop functionality from Angular Material which connects two lists by hash marks. **The problem is that now list which is dragable and list where items can be droped are separated becuase each one in in different component.** My question is how to connect these two lists to get functionality again? I am not asking about any code implementation, but only about passing values to the hash element references between this two components. 
[image]

Code:
Child Component 1 ([cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"):

```html
    <div class="msgList"
    cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="messagesArray" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"(scrolled)="onScroll()" [scrollWindow]="false">
```

Child Component 2 ([cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"):

```html
     <a mat-list-item class="navItem" (click)="onContainerChange(enumMessageContainer.DELETED_MESSAGES)"
           cdkDropList #doneList="cdkDropList"
           [cdkDropListData]="messagesMovedToDelete" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
           (cdkDropListDropped)="dropAndDelete($event)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            <span class="nav-caption">Trash</span>
        </a>
```

Comment: This question has probably [already been answered over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413175/how-to-use-angular7-angular-material-drag-drop-between-two-components).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Angular7 (angular material) drag drop between two components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413175/how-to-use-angular7-angular-material-drag-drop-between-two-components)