# Angular CDK drag with two lists

Tags: angular, angular-cdk-drag-drop

how are you? I have the following problem, I currently have 3 columns that have cards that move between the columns "OPEN", "BUG", "CLOSED". this is working.
Wanted to make columns move, change column position OPEN", "BUG", "CLOSED. Something like trello does.
Here is the code below: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-flsj7i?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "alternate". Please explain more.

Comment: Edited, take a look please.
I want to change the position of columns "OPEN", "BUG", "CLOSED". Something like Trello does;